# How to get the maximum length of each field in a csv file?

Tags: java, csv

I need to find out the maximum length for each field in a csv file .

For example in the following `cvs` file  because 
1) `var1` has the longest string  `shj` which is 3 characters  ,

2) `var2` has the longest string  `asdf` - 4 characters

3) `var3` has `asddfs` - 6 characters

```
var1,var2,var3
a,asdf,df
aa,,
shj,,asddfs
```

So , the result I need is the array   `int [] maxLength = {3,4,6}`

---

So far I am using CSV Reader API . Here is my code

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader (new FileReader(Looks.fileName));
        int [] maxLength = new int[reader.readNext().length];
        for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
            maxLength[i] = row[i].trim().length() ;
        }
        while ((row = reader.readNext()) !=null ) {
            for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
                maxLength[i] = Math.max(maxLength[i] , row[i].trim().length() );
            }
        }
        reader.close();
```

It works fine . But too slow for a huge file . I have around 100,000,000 rows .

Is there any efficient way to do this ? Can I use `setAsciiStream` somehow to estimate the length more efficiently ?

Comment: No other way then to read thru the whole file. If you have control over the file creation you may put max. length into the header (eg var1(3),var2(4),var3(6)).

Comment: By the way - what CSVReader API is this?

Comment: By the way, 100,000,000 rows, say 80 chars wide, is a 7.5GB file. WOW!

Comment: @PeterMmm I disagree . There must be some mechanism to do that faster . I have experience using setAsciiStream with csv for prepared statement purposes . It is lightning fast . . . There must be a work around

Answer (score 2):

Is `CSVReader` buffered?  If not, wrap your `FileReader` with a `BufferedReader` (and make it a nice large buffer size).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is about as efficient as it could be - it reads each byte once and once only, and it doesn't do any expensive seeking around the file.

It's possible that wrapping the `FileReader` in a `BufferedReader` could improve performance -- although it's not unlikely that `CSVReader` uses a `BufferedReader` internally.

There are physical limits on how quickly you can read 100,000,000 rows from disk. It's worth benchmarking the simplest program you can write which reads through a whole file, to see how long that takes, before deciding that your CSV reader is slow.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader filename);
char[] buffer = new char[1024**1024*10]; // 10MB; whatever
while(reader.read(buffer,0,buffer.length) >= 0) {
     // nothing
}
reader.close();
```

---

Update: confirmed my suspicions, assuming you are using OpenCSV.

Here is the source for OpenCsv: http://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/

The constructor for `CSVReader` wraps the `Reader` in a `BufferedReader` if it is not already a `BufferedReader`.

`CSVReader.readNext()` simply calls `BufferedReader.readLine()` repeatedly and does some pretty basic manipulation on the chars is acquires that way.

This is *the* fastest way of reading through a file: start at the beginning, read until you get to the end, using a buffer so that your underlying disk reads are the size the hardware and device drivers prefer.

Run the program above on a large file, and you'll find it takes about the same amount of time as your CSV parsing program -- because even though mine doesn't do any appreciable processing, it's has the same bottleneck as yours - the speed of reading from disk.

Indeed `cat largefile >/dev/null` (UNIX) or `type largefile >NUL` will take a similar time.

Run your code with a profiler and you'll find that it's spending more of its time waiting on `read()` (in a native method that's part of core Java) than anywhere else.

You can't do anything to your Java program to speed this up. You might be able to speed it up by tweaking the hardware and/or operating system - things like tuning filesystem parameters and driver settings, putting the file on RAMdisk or SSD, and so on.

Comment: That's not a very big buffer.  Did you mean `1024*1024*10`?

Comment: I disagree . There must be some mechanism to do that faster . I have experience using `setAsciiStream` with csv for prepared statement purposes . It is lightning fast . . . There must be a work around

Comment: @AndreiVasilev disagree all you like; let us know when you've found a way to magically get bytes off the disk faster than a BufferedReader.